# How to center chord names in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

By default, Lilypond seems to use left alignment for chord names, like this:

[image: left-aligned chord names]

Is there a way to center the chord names above the notes to which they refer? The "/G" being so far to the right of the "C" throws me off a bit.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I think this is pretty standard notation: the G is not on top of the next note, and the "C/G" text is tight enough that it still constitutes a single item. I wouldn't change it if I were you.

Comment: The chord itself is over the notes. The slash part should be after, as it just tells which inversion it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<<
  \new ChordNames \with {
    \override ChordName.X-offset = #ly:self-alignment-interface::aligned-on-x-parent
    \override ChordName.self-alignment-X = #CENTER }
  \chordmode { cis:7/ges q q q }
  { c'4 c' c' c' }
>>
```

But I'm skeptical that the results are all that convincing.

Comment: I agree that this is probably not convincing, or standard. As far as I'm aware, most music is rendered with chords left-aligned to the relevant notes. Nevertheless, nice that this can be done in Lilypond.

Comment: Thanks! Upon reflection, I think you're right about this. Thanks, user34030 and Evert!